# Global.asax - Application_Error - How can I get Page data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have this code:

```
using System.Configuration;

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    string ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    string StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
    string ExceptionType = ex.GetType().FullName;
    string UserId = Getloggedinuser();
    string WebErrorSendEmail =
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebErrorSendEmail"];

    // save the exception in DB
    LogStuffInDbAndSendEmailFromDb();
}
```

This is (most of) my code.
In a small percentage of cases, I don't get enough information though. I don't know what page the exception originated from.

How can I get any kind of information related to the page that the exception originated from?

Below is an example of the shortest message:

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
>
> at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) at
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) at
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   serializedState) at
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter,
>   String serializedState) at
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get the current request's URL and page like this :

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
    }
}
```